# Prove that the minimal disconnecting set of a graph, is a cut

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

Here is what I have to prove

**For any connected graph G with at least two vertices, any minimal disconnecting set of edges F, is a cut; and G - F has exactly two components.**

This is the definition of a cut given in our notes

*For any two subsets X, Y of V (G), define E(X, Y ) to be the set of all edges
with one end in X and one end in Y . A cut is a set of edges of the form E($S$, $\overline{S}$) where $S$ is a nonempty proper subset of V (G). Any cut is a disconnecting set (it removes all connections from $S$ to $\overline{S}$). However, not all disconnecting sets are cuts.*

Here's what I've got so far

---

Assume that F is a minimal disconnecting set of G, and for contradiction, assume that F is not a cut.

Since F is a disconnecting set, then G - F is not connected. Since F is not a cut, then there does not exist a bipartition ($S$, $\overline{S}$) such that F connects $S$ and $\overline{S}$. Therefore, for any bipartition ($S$, $\overline{S}$), G - F is connected (contradiction), or G - F has more than two components. In this case, there exists a set of edges H, that disconnects G such that there are only two components and H is smaller than F (Contradicts the minimality of F).

---

Firstly, I don't know if I've considered all cases. I only considered two. Is that all of them?

Secondly, I don't know how to prove that H is smaller than F. I feel like this is very easy to show, but for some reason, I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

So is the above proof correct?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

> Therefore, for any bipartition $(S, \bar S)$, $G - F$ is connected (contradiction), or $G - F$ has more than two components.

I'm not following the logic here. Since $F$ is fixed, $G - F$ does not depend in any way on $S$.

---

To prove this statement, my advice is to look at what the set $S$ has to be, not prove that it can't not exist. First, note that $G - F$ has exactly two components since adding back an edge of $F$ yields a connected graph. Next, let $S$ be the vertex set of one of the components of $G - F$ and look from there.

Comment: What part are you having trouble following the logic of? The first statement or the second?

Comment: Also, I think that F does relate to S. F is a cut, if we can find a bipartition S and $\overline{S}$ such that F connects S and $\overline{S}$.

Comment: @The_Questioner But if you are assuming that $F$ is not a cut then surely $F$ has nothing to do with $S$.

Comment: @The_Questioner As I am interpreting this, you are saying: "Assume $F$ is not a cut. Therefore if $F$ was the cut for $S$ then $G - F$ would either be connected or have more than two components."

Comment: I think I'm not explaining myself properly. I'm assuming that F is not a cut. So therefore, there cannot exist a set S, such that all edges in set F are all the edges between S and $\overline{S}$.

Comment: @The_Questioner Yes that's what it means for $F$ to not be a cut. But then right after that you consider $G - F$ and somehow relate it to $S$, how? You can't be saying that $F$ is the cut of $S$ right after saying $F$ is not a cut, that's nonsense. But then what does $S$ have to do with $G - F$?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. I'm not relating G - F to a particular set S. I'm saying that no matter what bipartion we use in G (denote any arbitrary bipartition as S), G - F is connected, or G - F has more than two components. I think it would make more sense to denote an arbitrary bipartition with B, instead. Maybe that'll make it clearer.

Comment: @The_Questioner I'm not going to continue this conversation further. We aren't getting anywhere.